# Change TextView in Fragment OnPreExecute

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to change a text view in the onPreExecute method in AsyncTask, however I keep getting Null Point Exception. Any help or alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

public class FragmentOne extends SherlockFragment
{

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    new LongOperation().execute("");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentone, container, false);
    return view;

}


private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        TextView txt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText("\nLoading...");
    }

    // etc etc etc
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code will work after doing the following change. :D The null pointer is come from getView() I think

```
    TextView txt = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentone, container, false);
        txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        new LongOperation().execute("");
        return view;

    }
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            txt.setText("\nLoading...");
        }

        // etc etc etc
    }
```

Comment: WORKS NOW! Maybe because I put this after setting view new LongOperation().execute("");

Answer (score 1):

`onPreExecute()` will be called before `execute()` returns. Hence, `getView()` in `onPreExecute()` will return `null`, because you have not even inflated the `View` yet, let alone returned it from `onCreateView()`.

Please:

- Remove `onPreExecute()` from your `AsyncTask`
- Inflate your layout first
- Call `findViewById()` and update the `TextView` in `onCreateView()` (what you are currently doing in `onPreExecute()`
- *Then* `execute()` your `LongOperation`
- Finally, return your inflated layout from `onCreateView()`

Comment: Thank you, I am using the answer Jeff Lee posted, I am not sure if that is a good way to do it, but it is working.

Comment: @user2122179: That approach should be fine. The only difference is that he kept `onPreExecute()`, whereas I would remove that method and move your `setText()` call into `onCreateView()`.